# How do I trim/strip URL down to get specific data?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How would I go about trimming/stripping the URL down to get specific data...

So: https://www.example.com/items/423455344/size-39

Would become: 423455344

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL is always going to match that format, you could do something like this.

```
function getData() {
    let foo = window.location.href.split("/"); //this gives you an array with the data between the slashes
    let searchController = "items"; //this is the key before the data you need
    for (let i=0; i<foo.length; i++){
        if (foo[i] === searchController){
            searchController = "/true/";
        } else if (searchController === "/true/") {
            return foo[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thank you, I made some research and I was able to achieve it by doing the following: 
var n = path.substring(path.indexOf("/items/")+7), removestr = n.substring(n.indexOf("/")), itemid = n.replace(removestr,'');

alert(itemid);